# Event Receiver - Cannot access item from Document Library if the user changed the name

Tags: event-receivers, rename, itemupdated

I have a library, that has versioning enabled.

On that library is an event receiver that does stuff, on `ItemUpdated`.

Ok, if the user uploads a document, and does not rename the document during the upload, everything works fine.

**But**

If the user uploads a document and renames it during the upload, the event receiver fails.

The code that fails is as follows:

```
SPListItem eItem = this._rootWeb.Lists["Listname"].GetItemByUniqueId(item.UniqueId);
```

Where `this._rootWeb` is a web in elevated permissions, and item is the listitem that is received by the event receiver.

The error received is:

> Value does not fall within expected range.

Any ideas how to do this so that it will be able to find the item even if the user renamed it?

Basically I am trying to get the item the user added, in elevated privileges.

Comment: instead of itemUpdated, can you try while item.updating event? this is synchronous event.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking the [`item.AfterProperties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventproperties.afterproperties.aspx) or the `item.AfterUrl`. It's weird that you can't get the item by using its `UniqueId`, but you have to check other things as well.

Is `item` in your case `properties.ListItem`, where `properties` is of type `SPItemEventProperties`? If not, that could also be the culprit as you should work with the item passed into your event receiver as property.

Comment: Hi :) Thanks for responding, the item is the splistitem, and yes it is the listitem from properties.ListItem... so all in all I have no idea why I would not be able to find it using its UniqueID.

Comment: As I said, check the before and after properties. Maybe the rename action does something weird. Also Renaming the list item might trigger the same event receiver twice, you have to check that too.

Comment: Adding in a delay before looking for the item has solved this. Something is clearly happening in parallel that needs to complete before you can access the item

Comment: Could be, did you try specifying the `Synchronization` property to synchronous? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.speventreceiverdefinition.synchronization.aspx